# Laravel 5.3 Guzzle and asynchronous request

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I try to handle asynchronous request with Guzzle and write the result of the request in my model:

```
$promise = $client->getAsync($url);

$promise->then(
            function (ResponseInterface $res) {

                $body = $res->getBody();    

                $MyModel = new  \App\Model\MyModel([
                        'data' => $body,
                        ]);

                $MyModel->save();

            },
            function (RequestException $e) {
                Log::error($e->getMessage());
            }
        );
```

But it doesn't work.

I also try to create a model outside of promise and pass it there:

```
$MyModel = new  \App\Model\MyModel();

$promise = $client->getAsync($url);

$promise->then(
            function (ResponseInterface $res) use($MyModel) {

                $body = $res->getBody();    

                $MyModel->data = $body;

                $MyModel->save();

            },
            function (RequestException $e) {
                Log::error($e->getMessage());
            }
        );
```

I don't have any error anywhere. But it does not work.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: It does not work means it goes to the error callback or nothing happened or throw an error?

Comment: It does not work means nothing happened in 'then' function. But request did send. I try to write anything in log in 'then' function. Nothing happened.